# Limit of trigonometric functions using identities.

Tags: trigonometry, limits

I would like to solve the following using only trig identities.

$$
\lim_{x \to \pi} {\cot2(x-\pi)}{\cot(x-\frac\pi2)}
$$

I have so far that the above is equal to
$$
\lim_{x \to \pi} \frac{\cos2(x-\pi)}{\sin2(x-\pi)}\frac{\cos(x-\frac\pi2)}{\sin(x-\frac\pi2)} = \lim_{x \to \pi} \frac{-\cos2x}{-\sin2x}\frac{-\sin x}{-\cos x} = \lim_{x \to \pi} \frac{\cos2x}{2\sin x\cos x}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac12\lim_{x \to \pi} \frac{\cos2x}{\cos x}\frac{1}{\cos x}=\frac12
$$

However, I am afraid the correct answer is $-\frac12$. Where am I going wrong? Also, if there is another method of solving this, I would be thankful for the insight.

Comment: $\cos(x)$ is an even function.

Comment: Of course, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , $\sin(2(x-\pi)) = \sin(2x)$ and $\cos(2(x-\pi) )= \cos(2x)$.  Look at the second step in your displayed equality.  You have $\cos(x - \pi/2) = \cos(\pi/2 - x) = \sin(x)$, but $\sin(x - \pi/2) = -\sin(\pi/2 - x) = \cos(x).$
Apply these and you will get it.

Comment: Thanks, I see that I didn't distribute the 2..

Comment: @revok: It's been good to up vote this answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

And $\cos(2x-2\pi)=\cos(2x)$ and $\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{2})=\sin(x)$ there.

Comment: ${{+1^{+}}^+}^+ \quad \ddot\smile$

Comment: @amWhy: Misssssss youuuuuu.